# Returning a list of winners from game/score data - SQL Server 2012

Tags: sql-server

I have data in this sample format:

```
name     score    game#
-----    -----    -----
PlayerA   100       1
PlayerB   50        1
PlayerC   75        2
PlayerD   150       2
PlayerE   100       3
```

and so on. I want to produce a list of "winners" such as below:

```
game#    winner     score
-----    -----      -----
1        PlayerA    100
2        PlayerD    150
3        .....      ...
```

Any suggestions? I am fumbling with using the MAX and GROUP BY and not getting all the columns I want. Thanks everyone!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sounds like a case for [ranking](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173825.aspx), so perhaps something a little like:

```
;WITH ranked AS (
    SELECT      RANK() OVER (PARTITION BY [Game#] ORDER BY Score DESC) AS Position, 
                Name, 
                Score,
                [Game#]

    FROM        Results
)
SELECT      [Game#],
            Name AS Winner,
            Score

FROM        ranked      

WHERE       ranked.Position = 1
```

Answer (score 0):

Just group by game number, calculate `max(score)` and then join result back with original table to get player having max score in each game:

```
select
    T.game,
    T1.name as winner,
    T.score
from
    (
        select
            game,
            max(score) as score
        from Your_Table
        group by game
    ) as T
    left outer join Your_Table as T1 on T1.game = T.game and T1.score = T.score
```

Comment: I'll try something like this - im not very good with self joins but this is what i was looking for I think! although the ranking example is also very good from the other user.